# Error when I try to send variables with Intent - NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to send an `ArrayList<Pet>` from a `Fragment` to `MainActivity.java` and from here, if you press an `ImageButton`(from the actionbar) it goes to another activity, in which I need the data from ArrayList. Well, I create an `Intent` in my `Fragment`class and a `Bundle` to receive this data in my `MainActivity`and I get an exception `NullPointerException` when I receive this data.

`Intent` code, from `Fragment` class

```
//Intent
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
String [] names = new String [pets.size()];
int []likesNumber = new int[pets.size()];
int [] photo = new int [pets.size()];
for (int i = 0;i<pets.size();i++){
    names [i] = pets.get(i).getPetName();
    likesNumber [i]=pets.get(i).getNumberOfLikes();
    photo[i] = pets.get(i).getFoto();
}
intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.pet_name),names);
intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.numberOfLikes),likesNumber);
intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.photo),photo);
startActivity(intent);
```

`Bundle` code to receive the data in `MainActivity` class:

```
//Bundle para initialize pets
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String [] names = bundle.getStringArray(getString(R.string.pet_name));
int [] nLikes = bundle.getIntArray(getString(R.string.numberOfLikes));
int [] photo  = bundle.getIntArray(getString(R.string.photo));
for (int i = 0; i<names.length;i++){
    pets.add(new Pet(nLikes[i],names[i],photo[i]));
}
```

I get the exception in this line:

`String [] names = bundle.getStringArray(getString(R.string.pet_name));`

I don't know the reason why I get a `NullPointerException`, because all the references are ok. If it's a logic error I wish you'd tell me too.

I don't know if it it's important but I commented that my `Fragment` is composed of a `RecyclerView`

The error is as follows:

> 08-26 15:07:03.640 2551-2551/es.uclm.mylittlepets E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL  EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                       Process: es.uclm.mylittlepets, PID: 2551
>                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{es.uclm.mylittlepets/es.uclm.mylittlepets.Layout.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String[]
>   android.os.Bundle.getStringArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object
>   reference
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'java.lang.String[]
>   android.os.Bundle.getStringArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object
>   reference
>                                                                               at
>   es.uclm.mylittlepets.Layout.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:55)
>                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

The way I solve this error:

> IN MY `Fragment` CLASS:

1.- I've created an interface `FragmentIterationListener` that I'll use to communicate with the `Activity`

```
public interface FragmentIterationListener{
    public void onFragmentIteration(Bundle parameters);
}
```

We create a `private FragmentIterationListener mcallback` attribute which we are going to use to send data to `Activity`.

2.- In `onAttach(Activity activity)` method we'll do the following:

```
try {
        mcallback = (FragmentIterationListener) activity;
    }catch(ClassCastException ex){
        Log.e("PetsFragment","The activity must implement the FragmentIterationListener interface");
    }
```

Thus, we assign to our attribute the `Activity` that is going to communicate.

3.- In the `onCreateView()` method, besides inflating the `Layout`, we instantiate the `RecyclerView`.

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvPets);
```

4.- In the `onViewCreated()` method, we establish the `RecyclerView` as a `LinearLayout`, then we initialize the `ArrayList <Pet> pets` and then we send it to `MainActivity` class:

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putParcelableArrayList("EXTRA_PETS", pets);
mcallback.onFragmentIteration(extras);
```

> IN MY `MainActivity.java` CLASS:

1.- We implement the interface that we created earlier.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PetsFragment.FragmentIterationListener{
```

2.- We implement the required method of this interface:

```
public void onFragmentIteration(Bundle parameters) {
    pets = parameters.getParcelableArrayList("EXTRA_PETS");
}
```

3.- We receive the data as follows: (in `onCreate()` method):

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
onFragmentIteration(bundle);
```

Comment: It is not a duplicate, seems he has issue with accessing resources in Fragments.

Comment: this question is not a duplicate one ...

Comment: I guess my question is not duplicated. At least I can't find another similar question that can help me

Comment: i think you have a problem of context , getting context of your activity from fragment . can you try this please :  String [] names = bundle.getStringArray(getResources().getString(R.string.pet_name));
try to add some log.v to test if getString(R.string.pet_name) returning a string befor you start activity

Comment: It's not the solution, it still give me the same exception.

Comment: could you post your code on github and send me the link . i want to help you .

Comment: In your fragment data is not passed using bundle .You have put data in bundle and pass that bundle to MainActivity

Comment: And how can I do it? I think I don't understand what you want to tell me